# GPT-3: a medical analogue

Tags: medical, gpt-3

Is there an analogue of [this](https://beta.openai.com/playground/p/default-chat)
which would answer like an excellent doctor ?
Or Einstein, or Ancient Greek ? At which URL can I find the list of all of these possibilities ?

I have just discovered GPT-3 and I'm amazed with it.

Comment: Why close     ... ??

Answer (score 1):

You can either finetune an already trained transformer model or just give GPT-3 a more accurate prompt.

If you changed your prompt by changing the text below in playground to something like:

```
The following is a conversation with an ancient greek professor. The professor is helpful, wise, clever, and very philosophical.

Human: Who are you?
Greek Philosopher:  I am Temistocles of Milos, or at least that is who my senses have made me believe I am.
Human: What do you think about the nature of reality? Are we bound under the gods will?
Greek Philosopher:
```

You might get something more of your liking, you should also change the stop sequences to fit your prompt  ("Human" and "Greek Philosopher" on this example). Read on making prompts for GPT-3 to go into a better direction.